# Error trying to open index page in XAMPP

Tags: indexing, xampp, runtime-error

I am trying to see the index page of the XAMPP I am talking about that:

http://postimg.org/image/91kkj9ryh/

But I get the following error message :

http://postimg.org/image/mcrv30pxn/

Today I installed XAMPP and everything worked fine , I shut down the PC for several hours and now I am receiving this error message. Why is this happening and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try localhost/splash.php

Is the file located in a directory called "xampp"? like c:/xampp/htdocs/xampp? if not just try what i said

Comment: It's not in htdocs . I still recieve the same error message.
Today by typing only localhost/xammp it worked , but after I have been opening php files in htdocs in the browser now it's not working.

Comment: open the folder "c:/xampp/htdocs" and put your file there by copying or cutting it and the  go to localhost/yourfilename.php if that doesnt work try wampp or reinstall xamp